# Multiple forms with same inputs name check which form input has error Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have something like this in my code:

```
@foreach($cars as $key => $car)
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'CarController@Update'])!!}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-6  control-label">Color</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {!!Form::text('carColor', $car->color, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm'])!!}
        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>   
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-6  control-label">Price</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {!!Form::text('carPrice', $car->price, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm'])!!}
        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>
{!!Form::close()}
@endforeach
```

The objective of this view is to update a car's price and color. But there are a lot so there's one form per car. In case the inputs don't pass the validation, how can I know which form inputs are the invalid since the inputs are named the same.

Comment: you want edit all cars details at same time ???

Comment: No, the user can edit one car at a time. There's one form per car. But in case the inputs of a certain form are invalid I want to know from which form it came

Comment: Why can you just list all cars with their details then add an edit button which you can redirect to an edit page or simply pop up a modal then do the edit request through ajax?

Comment: @Gokigooooks my question is a minified example of my real problem. I have a settings page, this settings are predefined. So I don't want the user to think he's creating, editing new stuff.  I want the user to have the idea of a configuration panel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the laravel has a session of old inputs but not for forms.
But this task is easy with javascript or jquery.

```
@foreach($cars as $key => $car)
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'CarController@Update'])!!}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-6  control-label">Color</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {!!Form::text('carColor', $car->color, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'carColor'])!!}

        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>   
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-6  control-label">Price</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        {!!Form::text('carPrice', $car->price, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id'=> 'carPrice'])!!}
        </div>                        
   </div>                        
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="carID" value="{{ $car->id }}">

        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="editDetails">edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
{!!Form::close()}
@endforeach
```

and in your javascript

```
$('#editDetails').on('click', function () {
    carColor = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('#carColor').val();
    carPrice = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('#carPrice').val();
    car_id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('#carID').val();
    _token=  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'); //add meta header in top head section see below

    //here you can also check validation like check for empty fields 

    $.ajax({
        url : 'url/to/edit/route',
        method : 'patch', //this could be post. whatever you defined as your route
        data : {
            carColor : carColor,
            carPrice : carPrice,
            carId : carId,
            _token : _token
        },
        success : function() {
            alert('successful edit!');
            //you can do something like
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<p>success</p>');
            //to show which line was successful
        },
        error : function(xhr,status,err) {
            //you can do something like append an alert div to the parent form element of the erroneous input row.
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<p>error editing here</p>');

        }
    });
});
```

add this meta tag with a csrf session as content  in the head tag of your master layout

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

Hope this would give you an idea on how you solve your problem.

---

**EDIT**
due to OP needing to handle this with no javascript

First add a hidden input of the key in foreach loop form to pass which row throws the error

```
<input type="hidden" id="key" value="{{ $key }}">
```

then in your controller you can add this to the error handling block

```
Session::flash('error', Input::get('key')); //use flash which behaves the same as as old input session
//a one time use session
```

and on inside the loop add an if statement checking for errors

```
@if(Session::has('error') || Session::get('error') == $key)
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>error here</h2> 
    </div>
@endif
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This actually solves my problem adding some front end code. But unfortunately, we're working the app 100% server side with Laravel

Comment: oh okay I'll make another answer which uses server side codes